# Home folder list from /etc/passwd, does not match what is in /home

Tags: linux, centos, home

I was looking at the list of created users in /etc/passwd. There are about 10 users, who show up like this in the list in /etc/passwd:

> user1:x:500:500::/home/user1:bin/bash
>   user2:x:501:501::/home/user2:bin/bash

However, when I navigate to /home, there are only 3 of the 10 users with home directories. Does anyone know why there is this discrepancy?

Comment: Well, it's possible to create a user without creating their home directory (`-M` to `useradd`) so it's not indicative of a problem per se

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The home dirs were never created for the other users.  Try the command `mkhomedir_helper <username>`

Comment: Ok, so even though it appears as though they have home directories created in /etc/passwd, the user who created the accounts may have specified not to create home directories? Is that correct?